# Around-the-world path breaking in Google Static Maps

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-maps-markers

I'm creating Google Static Maps with a path between markers and have come across certain coordinate combinations that break the path.

The path breaks in this example (markers @ Beijing, SF, NY, Azores, Rome):

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0xff0000cc|weight:3|39.904214,116.407413|37.77493,-122.419416|40.714353,-74.005973|38.721642,-27.220577|41.89052,12.494249&markers=39.904214,116.407413|37.77493,-122.419416|40.714353,-74.005973|38.721642,-27.220577|41.89052,12.494249&maptype=terrain&sensor=false&size=640x404

And works in this example (marker @ Rome removed)

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0xff0000cc|weight:3|39.904214,116.407413|37.77493,-122.419416|40.714353,-74.005973|38.721642,-27.220577&markers=39.904214,116.407413|37.77493,-122.419416|40.714353,-74.005973|38.721642,-27.220577&maptype=terrain&sensor=false&size=640x404

The cause is not crossing over the Greenwich Meridian as I initially thought.  It breaks even if I add a marker before that, seemingly any a point East of the automatically calculated centerpoint of the map...but only when the path starts on the other side of -180 longitude.

To prove that, you can see that the Beijing, SF, NY, Azores, Rome path displays correctly when I set the map centerpoint to -170,35

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0xff0000cc|weight:3|39.904214,116.407413|37.77493,-122.419416|40.714353,-74.005973|38.721642,-27.220577|41.89052,12.494249&markers=39.904214,116.407413|37.77493,-122.419416|40.714353,-74.005973|38.721642,-27.220577|41.89052,12.494249&maptype=terrain&sensor=false&size=640x404&center=-170,35

Unfortunately, I can't programmatically set center like this because I never know the collection of points I'm going to get, and it would be next to impossible to detect that the passed points would cause a line break.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First: you can calculate the center even if you don't know the collection of points (locations) at compile time: at runtime you know all the points (otherwise it would be not possible to insert the coordinates into the URL), therefore you can easily iterate over all the points and compute the center. You can computing the average of all coordinates and you get the geometric center (also called centroid): this is the easier way. Another way to do is to check the most distant pair of locations (for both, latitude and longitude) and then set the middle point as center: this requires slightly more coding (for instance to compute the longitude distance you need to take into account the you have to compute the distance in two directions, since it is possible to go 'around the world) and it has an higher complexity.

I don't go deeper in this topic because, even if you compute correctly the center of your points, this does NOT resolve the problem, and moreover the center provided automatically by the Google static map API is always correct: again the center is related to the problem, but it is not the (couse of the) problem.

An aspect that is trivial but important to keep in mind: Google static map draws a path between two locations always by considering the shortest path, i.e.  by drawing the shortest straight line.

Therefore if you are in a situation where your path has to go from a location A to a location B, and the shortest path between A and B goes 'around the world' (or better, it goes out from one side of the image), then the path appears 'borken' as in maps that you have shown. In practice A and B are near the left and right margins of the map, and the map can not be centered in some point along the shortest path between A and B because of the others point of the path. And this is what happen when you remove 'Rome': without Rome the map can be centered in a way that the path is not borken.

Formally, I think that the problem appears (i.e. the path is broken), when the projection of the path on the equator is longer than 360 degree of longitudes, and the path always goes in the same direction (i.e. always west to east or always east to west).

Google static map in this situation simply adds another world map next to the first one: if you set the zoom to the minimum, you can see up to three world maps. This is really impractical for several reasons:

- you can not zoom out infinitely;
- if you want also insert markers into the map they will be drawn only on the 'main' map;
- potentially you can have a path that goes around the world (passing in sequence from America, Europe, Asia, and America again and so on...) many times, and it would be really terrible to have so many little maps one after each other;

I googled a lot about this problem, and I didn't find any solution, there is a bug open on the bug tracker, but it is unsolved.

In my opinion the 'right' way to do is simply the following: at most one map and if a path has to goes out from one margin of the map/image, then it should appear on the opposite margin and continues to the destination, drawn on the same map.

So I found a first workaround:

- you draw your path, and with the same style (line's color, etc) you also draw the path in a reversed way (Google static map allows to draws multiple paths in the same map), i.e. path=A|B|C&path=C|B|A and this will solve the problem in many situations (i.e. the path exits from one side of the image and enters from the other). Unfortunately this not works always: if you have a path that cross the image margin two consecutive times, then you lose a portion of your path

To solve this problem I found a second workaround: 
- not draw simply the path and its reverse, but draw a different path for every pair of locations of the path (and reversed), i.e. for a path A->B->C then: path:A|B,path=B|C,path=C|B,path=B|A and this works always

The drawback is that in this way the URL becomes very long and the limit of 2048 characters for URLs is easily reached.

The best solution would be to compute manually the center, check manually where the path will cross the margin, and only for this portion of the path draw an additional path going between the two locations at the margin (and maybe also the reverse), but I do not think it really worth, although I do not think Google ever will solve this problem.